Problem With Soft Delete for One To Many Relationships
When I deleting an entity in my database I mark it as IsDeleted = true. Now the problem is when I am deleting an entity with relationships with other entities I mark it as Deleted in DB but I have to loop through its internal navigation properties to mark them as Deleted also.
Here is the BaseModel I inherit the IsDeleted from
public class BaseModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } 
}

and here is an example of what I do and I want to replace it with more performance and cleaner code
public async Task<string> Handle(DeleteCourseRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var course = await _baseService.GetByPropertyAsyncWithoutMap(c => c.Id == request.Id, c =>       c.Include(c => c.Centers).Include(c=>c.Sections));
    foreach (var center in course.Centers) center.IsDeleted = true;
    foreach (var section in course.Sections) section.IsDeleted = true;
    await _baseService.Delete(course);
    return "Done";
}

I tried looping over all internal navigation properties but we have some cases have a big chain of internal navigation properties so here come the problem.

To me this seems like a design issue. Since it's one-to-many why even have IsDeleted in Centers and Sections? They depend on Course anyway. If needed to know if they are "deleted" then navigate the property to Course.IsDeleted.

As an alternative to soft-deleting, have you considered using temporal-tables instead?

As far as I can tell from the above code, you read data from the database into memory, change the property and save it to the database. Of course, this is inefficient and slow. Consider performing this operation directly in the database using the ExecuteUpdate method.

Look at EF Core Tools & Extensions. Your task can be solved using triggers. There are extensions for working with triggers. There's also an extension with the tempting name SoftDelete. Look at it, maybe it will help?

This appears to be more of a misuse or misunderstanding of a soft-delete scenario than an issue with implementing it in EF. In an example like yours, marking a course (an aggregate root) as Deleted should be sufficient without flowing through to the centers and sections.
One key purpose for a soft delete over a hard delete is recoverability, where deletes can be undone if necessary. The point of having an IsDeleted on a section or center is that a section or center might be removed from a course. If you have 5 sections in a course, remove one, then remove the course and setting IsDeleted on the course sets IsDeleted on all sections, then your course is not recoverable. Removing the IsDeleted on the course would either leave all sections deleted or reinstate all 5 sections when at the time it was deleted, there were only 4 active ones.
Another use for soft-deletes is preserving data for historical evidence. In not all cases does deleting one record flow through to delete all associated records. For example if you have a customer with orders, marking a customer as deleted, it might be a requirement to invalidate any presently incomplete orders but does not invalidate all past, completed orders. (Where a hard-delete with FK constraints would insist on deleting the orders with the customer)
When looking at the implementation of a soft-delete your code should determine how the deleted state at any level might be affected by levels above it. Chances are you won't have code that looks at Sections or Centers as a top-level query without looking at Courses. There may be cases where you need to bubble IsDeleted state changes through entities, but these should considered carefully.
